# How to highlight text that is not available as typical HTML Element Text?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, find

We can press `Ctrl + F` in browser to find a text on the page as it gets highlighted if found a match. Even we can use good browser extensions to define our keywrords and then use the extension interface to highlight all occurrences etc.

Note: We must use Internet Explorer

**Problem:** For some particular application, the data is received as rich text box/rich text format. So we cannot use browser `Ctrl + F` or any extension to highlight the text. The simple reason is the text is inside the `value` attribute and not as typical HTML element text.

So is there a way the highlight effect can be achieved? please help
(for instance I want to highlight the word 'converted' from the following sample code)

```
<object name="TextData" classid="clsid:4cbabd-ff93-431-a92f-2fa664f970" codebase="ppp13.cab" id="TextData" style="border-width:0px;border-style:None;height:186px;width:98%;">
        <param name="WordWrap" value="True">
        <param name="PrintViewMode" value="True">
        <param name="FittedView" value="False">
        <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="False">
        <param name="ShowRuler" value="False">
        <param name="ShowToolBar" value="False">
        <param name="BorderMargin" value="True">
        <param name="RTFOutput" value="True">
        <param name="ReadOnlyMode" value="True">
        <param name="VertScrollBar" value="True">
        <param name="HorzScrollBar" value="True">
        <param name="TerKey" value="8YP41-NM5Q2-34BL3">
        <param name="Data" value="{\rtf1\ansi\deflang1033\ftnbj\uc1\deff1
{\fonttbl{\f0 \froman \fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f1 \fswiss Arial;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green255\blue255 ;\red0\green0\blue0 ;}
{\stylesheet{\f1\fs24\cf2\cb1\ulc2 Normal;}{\cs1\cf2\cb1\ulc2 Default Paragraph Font;}}
{\*\revtbl{Unknown;}}
\paperw12240\paperh15840\margl1800\margr1800\margt1440\margb1440\headery720\footery720\deftab720\formshade\aendnotes\aftnnrlc\pgbrdrhead\pgbrdrfoot
\sectd\pgwsxn12240\pghsxn15840\marglsxn1800\margrsxn1800\margtsxn1440\margbsxn1440\headery720\footery720\sbkpage\pgncont\pgndec
\plain\plain\f1\fs24\qc\lang1033\hich\f1\loch\f1\b 1cm \b0 = to \b 10mm \b0 Thus value of 10 cm is converted into 100mm.\plain\f1\fs24\par}
">
        <param name="InWebTer" value="True">

    </object>
```

Comment: Have yo tried anything? You likely won't be able to use the default search but rather would have to implement your own search.

Comment: No, no matter how much I try, there is no solution available. I can however develop win forms application (and thus can embed an IE object inside winform), so please inform how can I do that in win forms or any other way possible

Comment: Well, what you're doing is loading an object and as you require the use of internet explorer it's likely a ActiveX Element. So that element would have to implement the search.

Comment: Sorry, I do not have control over the development part of the web application. We use that application as end users, so please guide if you know some other workaround.

Comment: Copy the text into another tool and use the search function there, open a feature request with the vendor, use a different tool, write and embed a script that displays the value attribute as a regular text box, put up a post that tells users that it's not working. Well there are probably a bunch more of possible apporaches. With the information you have provided there is no easy solution and as you mentioned you did try something but don't detail anything about what you tried it's also kinda hard to guess.